# Interrupt circuit

Tags: arduino, transistors, sensor, interrupts

I'm using an 'Arduino like' board with a PIR sensor that gives 3.3V when movement is detected.

The board usually stays in sleep mode, and wakes up when a LOW value is given to a specific pin.

What's the simplest/best circuit to trigger the interrupt pin with a LOW signal, when the PIR output goes HIGH?

Comment: Why not just flip the polarity of the interrupt?

Comment: yes I could, but I should modify the library I am using, so I prefer another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your interrupt pin is pulled high, and the interrupt can stay low after being triggered, you can use a transistor as a switch [1](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/r/400-400/assets/learn_tutorials/1/9/3/logic-inverter-circuit.png).  If the low interrupt must only be momentary, 555 timers can generate pulses from the leading edge of a state change.